# How can I color a paragraph from <head> in HTML?

Tags: html, css

So I want to color a paragraph that is further down than the `<head>` and the paragraph has the `<ol>` and ***here*** its the list `</ol>`.

How can I color the list from `<head>`?

Comment: Wouldn't this be done by using CSS?

Answer (score 2):

simply tag the corresponding element which want to color if paragraph you can do like this

```css
p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        <p>here's your answer</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Didn't he mention `<ol>` instead of  `<ul>`? (Not that this invalidates your answer)

Comment: @UweKeim I have edited if it seems helpful  you can up vote this

Answer (score 2):

```css
ol li p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li><p>pragraph color will be Red</p></li>
</ol>
```